# Remove Segment From URL Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

Is it possible to remove a segment from URL but still redirecting it to location. I use a MY_Controller for all the controllers.

Example: localhost/project/maintenance

Would become localhost/project

**Router.php**

```
$route['default_controller'] = "catalog/common/home/index"; // Always Default Controller
$route['404_override'] = '';

$route['maintenance'] = "catalog/common/maintenance"; // Maintenance Controller
```

**I tried this below know luck**

```
if($this->config->item('system_maintenance') == FALSE) {
    $route['default_controller'] = "catalog/common/home/index";
} else {
    $route['default_controller'] = "catalog/common/maintenance/index";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I Think I got it working now in routes works fine now so far.

```
if($this->config->item('system_maintenance') == TRUE) {
$route['default_controller']    = "catalog/common/maintenance/index";
} elseif ($this->config->item('system_maintenance') == FALSE) {
$route['default_controller']    = "catalog/common/home/index";
}
```